# How to check which NSViewController is active swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

I have an app with multiple ViewControllers and I need to check which ViewController is active at the moment in AppDelegate. For example, I'll create a timer that runs function that checks if the particular ViewController is active and if it is, do some stuff. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hey Niktin, Are you loading some kind of container controller that will hold these view controllers, like a TabBar controller, or a Navigation controller?

Comment: No, there are just some viewcontrollers, connected with segues

Comment: window.view.rootViewController ? (this may be iOS only)

Comment: What actually do you mean by "is active"? Whether it has focus?

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes, when the user works with it

Comment: @Okapi, this doesn't work

Comment: @NiktinRoman what does not work? Is there an error message?

Comment: @SebastianDressler yes, (use of unresolved identifier "window", written in AppDelegate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information by accessing the root view controller in AppDelegate or anywhere else:

```
let activeController = window.rootViewController
```

However, since you want to use a timer to execute some code in that view controller, it might be more preferable to send a [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/). Since the "active" view controller should be aware, that it is active, you can specifically connect and disconnect the notification listeners.

Comment: Thanks much, but the code you've written is not working (use of unresolved identifier "window", written in AppDelegate), but the idea with NSNotification seems good

Comment: You can get the active window by calling [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.

Comment: for macos it is `window.contentViewController`

Answer (score 5):

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
```

Will return the current window that has keyboard access. From there you can introspect on the NSWindow object to determine which it is.

Also if you have a need for it to programmatically active windows.

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows
```

Will return an array of NSWindows in your application currently open.

```
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
```

Will bring the window in focus, even from being minimized and make it the key window for keyboard control.

```
window.makeKeyWindow()
```

Will just bring the window in focus and make it the key window. It won't bring it out of minimization.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern in my AppDelegate to see which view controller has the document I'm currently working on:

```
 var vc: ViewController? = nil

 func iHaveFocus() -> Bool {
        let win = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow
        if (win != nil) {
            vc = win!.contentViewController as? ViewController
            if (vc != nil) {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            vc = nil
        }
        return false
    }

// Then to see which document gets something like a paste...

 @IBAction func pasteStuff(_ sender: Any) {
    if (iHaveFocus()) {
        vc!.pasteStuff()
    }
}
```